# Is it possible to use Single Sign-Out for Azure B2C SPA application? Where do you describe the logout URL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

The Azure B2C documentation states that it supports Single Log Out (SLO) but I can't figure out how this works with a registered SPA application.

If one app is registered in B2C `app1.mydomain.com` and another app `app2.mycomain.com` As well, there is a `Front-channel logout URL` [Which is described](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003445#handling-single-sign-out-requests) to be something that will log out the application specifically:

> When Azure AD B2C receives the logout request, it uses a front-channel HTML iframe to send an HTTP request to the registered logout URL of each participating application that the user is currently signed in to. Note, the application that triggers the sign-out request will not get this log-out message. Your applications must respond to the sign-out request by clearing the application session that identifies the user.
>
> - For OpenID Connect and OAuth2 applications, Azure AD B2C sends an HTTP GET request to the registered logout URL.
> - For SAML applications, Azure AD B2C sends a SAML logout request to the registered logout URL.

This is a setting that is in the app registration and for SPA applications there is nothing that you can do to reference the "log out" url.

The front-channel logout URL is predefined as `https://<your-tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<your-tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<PolicyName>/oauth2/v2.0/logout`

So if this is supposed to send an HTML iframe to "logout" of the other applications that it knows about. Where can you add the logout URL? It's not in the custom policy or flow.

[Other documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1076215/problem-implementing-front-channel-logout-with-ang?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1081911#newest-answer-comment) suggest this:

> Yes, you need to manually clear the local storage or handle it using your application.

What does that mean? How can we manually clear the cookies if the functionality of the SLO can't work because it is not knowing about the logout URL's of the applications?

Can we edit the front-channel logout URL to our domains i.e. app1.mydomain.com/logout which then would do something to hit the endpoint and then redirect them to the original Front-Channel logout URL?

Or, do we have to run the checks on the token for each app upon browser refresh and silent refresh capabilities of B2C?

Answer (score 0):

## Configuration

Yes, you can set a per-application single-sign-out URL. The page you linked to contains details on how to do that for an app registration, it's in [the section just before the one you linked to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-your-application):

> #### Configure your application
>
> In order for an application to participate in single sign-out:
>
> - For SAML service providers, configure the application with the [SingleLogoutService location in its SAML metadata document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider#override-or-set-the-sign-out-url-optional). You can also configure the app registration `logoutUrl`. For more information, see [set the logout URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider#override-or-set-the-sign-out-url-optional).
> - For OpenID Connect or OAuth2 applications, set the `logoutUrl` attribute of your app registration manifest. To configure the logout URL:
>
>   1. From the Azure AD B2C menu, select **App registrations**.
>   2. Select your application registration.
>   3. Under **Manage**, select **Authentication**.
>   4. Under the **Front-channel logout URL**, configure your logout URL.

### 1. From the Azure AD B2C menu, select App registrations

[image: Azure AD B2C menu]

### 2. Select your application registration.

[image: Select app registration]

### 3. Under **Manage**, select **Authentication**.

[image: Select authentication]

### 4. Under the **Front-channel logout URL**, configure your logout URL.

[image: Configure logout URL]

## How it works

The way this then works is B2C keeps a record of each app that has signed in, when any one app signs out B2C will display a (blank) page that calls each single-sign-out URL for each other app in an iFrame. Each of those single-sign-out URLs should point to a sign-out URL in the relevant application so the application can clear its cookies/session storage as needed.

For example, if you configure the following single-sign-out URLs in the relevant B2C app registrations:

| App | URL |
| --- | --- |
| https://app1.com | https://app1.com/sign-out |
| https://app2.com | https://app2.com/done |
| https://app3.com | https://app3.com/end-session |

Then you'd see the following:

1. Sign into https://app1.com
2. Sign into https://app2.com
3. Sign into https://app3.com
4. Sign out of https://app2.com

   1. Redirect to `https://<your-tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<your-tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<PolicyName>/oauth2/v2.0/logout`

      1. Display single-sign-out page

         1. Call https://app1.com/sign-out in iFrame
         2. Call https://app3.com/end-session in iFrame
      2. End B2C session
      3. Redirect back to app2
   2. End local session

Comment: This is a little confusing. For OpenID Connect or OAuth2 applications, set the logoutUrl attribute of your app registration manifest. To configure the logout URL: What are the instructions to do this. how do you add it to the manifest and does this work for SPA apps?

Comment: I see the manifest instruction for AD but what about B2C: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#manifest-reference

Comment: You need to follow the numbered list in [the link I provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-your-application) (and quoted in my answer) that explains how "To configure the logout URL."

Log into the Azure Portal, make sure you're in your B2C directory and follow those numbered steps _exactly_.

**Edit**: updated link as it was scrolling past the anchor it referenced.

Comment: Hi, @dave thanks this says it's for SAML but is this for Oauth2 and openId connect as well?

Comment: I don't know why the docs are so bad at making the point clear. see this statement-> Under the Front-channel logout URL, configure your logout URL. <- can you see where this doesn't clearly state what the configuration is. More confusing is the SAML references. If it is something that should be updated in the manifest why can't it just say that directly?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew there are two bullet points, one gives instructions for setting the logout URL when using SAML, the second gives instructions for setting the logout URL when using OIDC. The OIDC bullet has a numbered list of the exact steps that you need to go through. The text before that numbered list isn't great, but if you do exactly what the numbered list says then that will configure the sign-out URL for OIDC apps.

Comment: I've added some image to show where in the UI each step should take you.

Comment: Ok thanks. This is super clear. We'll implement and confirm this is working.

Comment: Hi Dave this doesn't work. We have set it up exactly as stated. When you logout from one app there is no iframe or anything visible in the network tab of the other open tabbed application that is getting a request. I don't know if anything would be visible there either. However, it does not logout the other application. Is there anything else in the custom policy we need to do to refer to each app registrations? As of now the JWT reference whether that is there or not doesn't seem to do anything. We can remove it and single sign on works as it did before. I feel something in the CP isn't...

Comment: If you're not getting a page in B2C with iFrames at all then I'd suspect that's something to do with your policy setup. Only the [steps listed in MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003445#single-sign-out) are needed. Have you definitely set up the JWT issuer technical profile and SingleSignOn in your relying party policy? Can you update your question to include those?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew thinking about it some more, the other possibility is that it just takes time for the change to take effect. I've had an instance recently where it took a few hours (I ended up leaving it overnight) before I saw the change to my app registration result in the sign-out URL being called.

Comment: It doesn't work. There are a lot of other people saying the same in other channels.

Comment: @DaveD Thank you for the thorough explanation, but regrettably, this method is not effective.

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Did you happen to fix it in your app?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Did you manage to set single sign out correctly? We have the same issue. All looks correct in code and configuration, but other applications are not triggered to log out.